# Как при выводе ответа убрать лишние пробелы?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написал код, но при выполнении выдает неверный ответ(выводит все верно, но ставит лишние пробелы перед знаком "." в первом тесте)

```
n, m, p = map(int, input().split())
 
 
def fun(n, m, k):
    lstn = list(range(1, n + 1))
    lstm = list(range(n + 1, n + m + 1))
    lst = ['.'] * 2
    flag = 0
    if m < n:
        n, m = m, n
        lstn, lstm = lstm, lstn
        lstm.reverse()
        lstn.reverse()
        flag = 1
    k = min(2 * n * m + 2 * n - m, k)
    ki, kf = divmod(k, 2 * m + 2)
    if ki:
        lstm.extend(lstn[-ki:])
        del lstn[-ki:]
    if kf:
        lst.insert(1, lstn.pop())
        kf -= 1
        if kf:
            for _ in range(m):
                lstn.append(lstm.pop(0))
                kf -= 1
                if not kf:
                    break  
        if kf:
            lstm.insert(0, lst.pop(1))
            kf -= 1
 
        if kf:
            for _ in range(m):
                lstm.insert(0, lstn.pop())
                kf -= 1
                if not kf:
                    break           
    if flag:
        lstn, lstm = lstm, lstn
        lstm.reverse()
        lstn.reverse()
    print(*lstn, *lst, *lstm)
 
 
fun(n, m, p)
```

пример работы программы на данный момент:

**Номер теста**

1

**Ввод**

```
2 3 2
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
1 3 .2. 4 5
```

**Вывод**

```
1 3 . 2 . 4 5
```

Comment: Ваш код совсем не большой. На этом сайте прилагают простыни в разы больше и это норма. Вставьте его напрямую в вопрос, ибо прикреплённая ссылка со временем может стать недействительна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте аргумент `sep=''`. Он задаёт разделитель для множества выводимых аргументов функции `print`.

То есть:

```python
print(*lstn, *lst, *lstm, sep='')
```

Если же необходимо, чтобы данная политика разделителей применялась только к одному из аргументов, предлагаю разделить данный `print` на 3 отдельных, а чтобы между ними на вставлялся перевод строки использовать аргумент `end=' '`, указывающий, что после выведенной на консоль информации следует поставить пробел, а не перевод строки. Итог получится такой (насколько я понял, первый аргумент содержит два числа, второй – две точки и число, третий – тоже два числа):

```python
print(*lstn, end=' ')
print(*lst, sep='', end=' ')
print(*lstm) # Здесь в конце поставится перевод строки, если не нужен, можно так же убрать аргументом end
```

Comment: спасибо, только нужно чтобы не все элементы разбивались по пробелу, а только именно удалялись пробелы перед точками(добавил пример в вопрос)

Comment: @Андр, сейчас дополню ответ, а Вы пока отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос в соответствии с моим комментарием.